# need to update buddy press topbar

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

i am new to word press and trying to modify Buddy Press top bar.

my current top bar is

[image]

i want to make user area top bar like

[image]

the basic difference is to put the login user image/aviator on left side of bar.

and also if possible remove visit link from right side.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you start by creating a custom theme (or plugin if you prefer) that is a child theme  of the `bp-default` theme. Follow the instructions [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) or [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin).

From there you can remove the Visit menu like so:

```
remove_action( 'bp_adminbar_menus', 'bp_adminbar_random_menu',        100 );
```

When it comes to the avatar, the easiest solution is probably to unregister BuddyPress default admin bar logo `bp_adminbar_logo`, create a replacement function to output the avatar, and finally register that function instead.

```
remove_action( 'bp_adminbar_logo',  'bp_adminbar_logo' );

function my_adminbar_logo() {
    echo '<a href="' . bp_core_get_userlink( bp_loggedin_user_id(), false, true ) . '">';
    bp_loggedin_user_avatar( 'type=thumb&width=40&height=40' );
    echo "</a>";
}

add_action( 'bp_adminbar_logo',  'my_adminbar_logo' );
```

There, just add some CSS and you're done :)